# Notfication Handler causing error when sending Amazon Textract Request

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

Im trying to us amazon textract to parse a PDF, this is required to be an asynchronous operation as outlined in their [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/sync-calling.html) .

The code im using follows this code I found on [github](https://github.com/Associated-Computer-Experts/Web-Services/blob/master/code_samples/src/main/java/com/associated/textract/AnalyzeDocumentAsync.java)

I've localised the error to understanding that the error is being caused due to the Notification Handler that is being submitted as part of the request - however this is needed later on when getting the results.

I should note that I've already tried the manual configuration that [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/async.html) shows and used the ARNs directly, but I had the same issue.

My s3 bucket is in a VPC however I am confident my IAM is set up correctly as I've managed to extract text from a png file (which uses a different non-asynchronous method). These are the policies added.

- AmazonSQSFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAcess
- AmazonTextractFullAccess
- AmazonTextractServiceRole
- AmazonSNSRole
- AmazonSNSFullAccess

These are the two methods being used, creating a topic and queue, and then the StartDocumentTextDetection.

```
// Creates an SNS topic and SQS queue. The queue is subscribed to the topic. 
static void CreateTopicandQueue(){
        //create a new SNS topic
        snsTopicName="AmazonTextractTopic" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(snsTopicName);
        CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = sns.createTopic(createTopicRequest);
        snsTopicArn=createTopicResult.getTopicArn();

        //Create a new SQS Queue
        sqsQueueName="AmazonTextractQueue" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest(sqsQueueName);
        sqsQueueUrl = sqs.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();
        sqsQueueArn = sqs.getQueueAttributes(sqsQueueUrl, Arrays.asList("QueueArn")).getAttributes().get("QueueArn");

        //Subscribe SQS queue to SNS topic
        String sqsSubscriptionArn = sns.subscribe(snsTopicArn, "sqs", sqsQueueArn).getSubscriptionArn();

        // Authorize queue
        Policy policy = new Policy().withStatements(
                new Statement(Effect.Allow)
                        .withPrincipals(Principal.AllUsers)
                        .withActions(SQSActions.SendMessage)
                        .withResources(new Resource(sqsQueueArn))
                        .withConditions(new Condition().withType("ArnEquals").withConditionKey("aws:SourceArn").withValues(snsTopicArn))
        );


        Map queueAttributes = new HashMap();
        queueAttributes.put(QueueAttributeName.Policy.toString(), policy.toJson());
        sqs.setQueueAttributes(new SetQueueAttributesRequest(sqsQueueUrl, queueAttributes));


        System.out.println("Topic arn: " + snsTopicArn);
        System.out.println("Queue arn: " + sqsQueueArn);
        System.out.println("Queue url: " + sqsQueueUrl);
        System.out.println("Queue sub arn: " + sqsSubscriptionArn );
    }
```

```
private static void StartDocumentTextDetection(String bucket, String document) throws Exception{

        //Create notification channel
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel()
                .withRoleArn(roleArn)
                .withSNSTopicArn(snsTopicArn);


        S3Object s3ObjectTextract = new S3Object();
        s3ObjectTextract.setBucket(bucket);
        s3ObjectTextract.setName(document);

        StartDocumentTextDetectionRequest req = new StartDocumentTextDetectionRequest()
                .withDocumentLocation(new DocumentLocation()
                        .withS3Object(s3ObjectTextract))
                .withJobTag("DetectingText")
                .withNotificationChannel(channel);

        System.out.println("Found the document: " + document);
        System.out.println(req.toString());

        StartDocumentTextDetectionResult startDocumentTextDetectionResult = textract.startDocumentTextDetection(req);

        startJobId=startDocumentTextDetectionResult.getJobId();
    }
```

This is my stack trace of the error:

```
{DocumentLocation: {S3Object: {Bucket: <bucketname>,Name: <filename>,}},JobTag: DetectingText,NotificationChannel: {SNSTopicArn: <Arn>,RoleArn: <arn}}
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.textract.model.InvalidParameterException: Request has invalid parameters (Service: AmazonTextract; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: <>)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1712)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1367)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.doInvoke(AmazonTextractClient.java:816)
    at com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.invoke(AmazonTextractClient.java:783)
    at com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.invoke(AmazonTextractClient.java:772)
    at com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.executeStartDocumentTextDetection(AmazonTextractClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.services.textract.AmazonTextractClient.startDocumentTextDetection(AmazonTextractClient.java:708)
    at AnalyzeDocumentAsync.StartDocumentTextDetection(AnalyzeDocumentAsync.java:279)
    at AnalyzeDocumentAsync.ProcessDocument(AnalyzeDocumentAsync.java:158)
    at AnalyzeDocumentAsync.main(AnalyzeDocumentAsync.java:91)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I've exactly same issue, did you find a solution for same?